# How can I abort an evaluation in Clojure Box (Emacs)?

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, slime

I've been caught up in long running computations lately thanks to [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) and I'd like to know how to abort an evaluation and return to the REPL prompt. I'm running the standard [Clojure Box](http://clojure.bighugh.com/) version of Emacs. I tried the obvious *REPL > Interrupt Lisp Process* and *Slime > Interrupt Command* but neither kill the execution and return my REPL prompt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hit control c twice.  If you're in `*slime-repl clojure*` then C-c C-c will kill the process and return you to the repl prompt.  If you're in the `*inferior-lisp*` buffer, then you'll probably kill the clojure process, meaning that you'll have to restart slime (with `M-x slime`).  If you don't have a slime repl buffer then, `M-x slime-repl` should give you one.  You can use this as a repl to get a few extra features (try pressing the comma and tab, and see what's available ;)

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. Both of the commands I listed in the question - Interrupt Lisp Process & Interrupt Command - are listed as C-c C-c in the menu. Neither works.

Comment: *huh* ... works for me ... are you in the slime repl ? or a buffer called *inferior-lisp* ??

Comment: It's strange; this *sometimes* works for me, but other times not

Answer (score 2):

When things get really fowled you can kill your lisp instance with `M-x slime-quit-lisp` and then restart it with `M-x slime`